# Restore messed upp Assemblies Mvc VS2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I've seem to have messed up my environment. When i create a MVC 2 Web Application project i face this error. Any idea of what i need to reinstall/uninstall?

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_RbcACX1DmM8/SztdvDr0wXI/AAAAAAAAASM/QXCAIHEShEA/s800/Clipboard02.jpg](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_RbcACX1DmM8/SztdvDr0wXI/AAAAAAAAASM/QXCAIHEShEA/s800/Clipboard02.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install MVC 2 Beta? [It's completely incompatible with VS 2010](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/19/aspnetmvc-2-and-vs2010.aspx). You cannot install it on a machine where you want to also use MVC in 2010. You need to use MVC 2 Preview 2 (or earlier) for your VS 2008 projects.

You can also wait for the next VS 2010 beta, which will include an updated MVC 2.

Comment: It's very possible. I downloaded some stuff with Microsoft Web Platform Installer and probably didn't pay attention. Weirdly enough the project compiles and runs ok. I'll accept this and wait for the next VS2010.

Comment: Right; the MVC 2 runtime bits work fine for 2010; it's the tooling/IDE which aren't supported for 2010.

Answer (score 0):

VS2K10 comes with MVC.  If you installed one of the betas, it is not compatible.  You should use the distributed version.